Describing Different Deployment Environments Using C4Model
How would you recommend describing a different deployment environments in Structurizr?
For example:

An Acceptance environment may contain less nodes than a Production one
Different environments may utilise VMs rather than metal, or use differing sizes based on the cloud provider you use
Some environments may have geo-redundancy or availability zones
Development and Testing may share an environment, but are separated by namespace (when talking k8s).

Are these the kind of representations that are appropriate to define within the C4 Model?

Context, Container, Component, Code. That’s what the C4Model is about. The model does not contain  information about differences in DTAP environments

@RikD But it does have deploymentNode and deploymentEnvironment elements defined.

The C4 model describes a deployment diagram that shows how systems or containers are deployed onto infrastructure that addresses this.
There is an example of a Deployment Diagram, created using Structurizer, on the C4 model website:

The title of the diagram can reflect the environment. In this example, the title is [Deployment] Internet Banking System - Live. You could make diagrams such as [Deployment] Your System - Acceptance and [Deployment] Your System - Production. Within the notes, you would use the deployment node annotations to elaborate on operating systems or show the existence of containers and container orchestration systems. You can also put your environments and label them for regions or availability zones.
However, you can also drop out of C4 models for this and use UML deployment diagrams using its notation as well. A lightweight approach, such as what Martin Fowler describes as UML as Notes or UML as Sketch can help to get away from some heavyweight aspects of the current versions of UML and let you focus on communicating the relevant aspects of your architecture and design.

This is great, thanks @Thomas Owens. I'll take a look at this over the coming days (travelling).

Thomas, that was exactly what I was after, thanks!
